# Array.prototype.map is not a function when passing a function generated by Function.prototype.call as argument

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sometimes I use the Array.prototype.map methode like so :

```
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4'].map(parseFloat); // the result is [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> **parseInt** takes 2 arguments it returns incorrect values in this case

Now what I'm trying to do is instead of this code :

```
var  array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map( function (item) { 
    return item.toUpperCase(); 
}); // the result is ['A', B', 'C', 'D']
```

I tried this :

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map(''.toUpperCase.call);
```

can someone explain to me why I get an error that says :

> Uncaught TypeError: ["a","b","c","d"].map is not a function

Comment: For a better understanding of why this doesn't work I would recommend reading [**You Don't Know JS: *this* & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is you pass the function `''.toUpperCase.apply` which **is the same** as `Function.prototype.apply`: it isn't bound.

What happens is equivalent to

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map(function(v, i, arr){
   return undefined.apply(v, i, arr)
});
```

If you bind it using

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map(''.toUpperCase.apply.bind(''.toUpperCase));
```

then you have a second problem: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't pass only one parameter to your callback. It also pass the index and the whole array.

You could "fix" the two problems with

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map(function(v){ return ''.toUpperCase.apply(v) });
```

(more an explanation than a fix, right)

Using `call` is easier and **can** be fixed:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map(''.toUpperCase.call.bind(''.toUpperCase));
```

which should be written as

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map(Function.prototype.call.bind(''.toUpperCase));
```

**Side note:** you were lucky to use `parseFloat` in the first example. Try with `parseInt`.

Comment: ...at which point you could simply use `return v.toUpperCase();`

Comment: Yes I found out that there will be a problem when using `''.toUpperCase.apply` but why is there a problem when using `''.toUpperCase.call` even if you can pass as many arguments as you want, the result will always be correct

Comment: Why use `''.toUpperCase` instead of `String.prototype.toUpperCase`? Feels the same way to me as using `(function () {}).call` instead of `Function.prototype.call`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `''.toUpperCase.call` to `Array.map`, though it will pass the argument correctly, the `call` function disintegrates from `toUpperCase` function, which holds the implementation details.

So, now the `Function.call` does have the correct argument passed to it by the `Array.map` callback function, but it holds no reference to `''.toUpperCase` function.

> [**MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) You can assign a different `this` object when calling an existing
>   function. `this` refers to the current object, **the calling object**.

So `''.toUpperCase.call("a")` is entirely different to `call("a")`, which is what is happening when you pass `''.toUpperCase.call` to `Array.map`

Comment: I'm combining it with `Array.prototype.map` which passes the value of each element as argument to the give function wich is in this case the `''.toUpperCase.call`