# JavaScript Function Context Incorrect

Tags: javascript

I noticed a weird thing in javascript. Consider the below:

```
var fn = ''.toUpperCase.call
console.log(typeof fn); // "function"
fn(); // Uncaught TypeError: `fn` is not a function
```

The above was executed on my Chrome's Developer Console. Version is `43.0.2357.81 m`.

The `typeof` operator clearly shows that `fn` is a function, but the error suggests otherwise.

I've noticed that `Function.apply` shows at least some meaningful error message.

So, when is a function, not a function?

Comment: Please show *how* exactly you're calling `fn`.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined is not a function` when calling `fn`, *not* `fn is not a function`.

Comment: @deceze this isn't a production code..I just happened to see a question, pondering on which, I came across this weird stuff.

Comment: Sure. Still, please show a full example of what code produces what error.

Comment: Please clarify if consoele is a typo and edit if not

Comment: I guess you are calling `fn()` and `call` expects to be executed on a function, which your not doing, your calling on `undefined`. In the latest chrome, the error shows `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: @Burkhard it was a typo indeed. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: Firebug has a more insightful error message: `TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined`. Basically `call()` needs to be called on an object (`this`), which is lost, being called outside the original statement.

Comment: Saw a similar issue on [Remy Sharp's Twitter](https://twitter.com/rem/status/601481375854759937) feed a while back: http://jsconsole.com/?c%20%3D%20Function.prototype.call.bind()%3B%20console.log(c%20instanceof%20Function%2C%20typeof%20c)%3B%20c()%3B

Comment: @deceze that's the full code I have. I've made it one.

Comment: Interestingly, since the "bug" is simply that the `this` inside `fn()` is not a function (thus, `fn()` is actually trying to do `undefined()` and it should fail since undefined is not a function). This can be made to work by doing: `fn.call(function(){return 'hi'})` which sets `this` correctly inside `fn()`

Comment: BTW `String.prototype.toUpperCase.call()` gives this error in Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.toUpperCase called on null or undefined"

Comment: https://nemisj.com/some-interesting-aspects-of-call-method-in-javascript/

Comment: @MattBrowne: Correct, the first argument of `.call()` is the `this` value you want it to operate on. So since an empty argument in js is `undefined` you're basically trying to do: `undefined.toUpperCase()`

Comment: @MattBrowne that's reasonable since you've not passed the first argument, and it will be `undefined` by default

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Context in Javascript is always established by the way you *call* a function.

```
var fn = ''.toUpperCase.call
```

This assigns the prototype implementation of the `call` function to `fn`. If you now call `fn()`, there's no context to the call. `call` would try to invoke the function object it was associated with. However, that context is established at call time. Since you're not giving it any context at call time, some internal component of `call` is throwing an error.

You'd have to do this:

```
fn.call(''.toUpperCase)
```

That's right, you `call` the `call` function, establishing a context, namely the `toUpperCase` string function. In this specific case this would lead to another error inside `toUpperCase`, since *it* is not bound to a specific context. You'd need to establish that context explicitly as well:

```
var fn = ''.toUpperCase.call
fn.call(''.toUpperCase.bind(''))
```

Also see [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/476)

Comment: so do you think, [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594471/array-prototype-map-is-not-a-function-when-passing-a-function-generated-by-funct/30594762#30594762) is the answer to the linked question too?

Comment: @Amit Yeah, you're basically saying the same thing there.

Comment: `Context in Javascript is always established by the way you call a function.` Unless it's an arrow function, or the function has been bound.

Answer (score 3):

[deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30595705/227299) is correct, I just want to explain it from a different point of view.

Your `fn` is a reference to `Function.prototype.call` which needs to be called with a function as its `this` reference, in this case, the context for `call` is `String.prototype.toUpperCase`, which was inherited through `''.toUpperCase`

On top of that, `String.prototype.toUpperCase` also has to be called with a specific context, the string to upper case.

Here's another way to code what you wanted that may help you understand what is going on.

```js
    var str = 'aaa';
    var upper = ''.toUpperCase;
    var fn = upper.call;
    // Now we have to specify the context for both upper and fn
    console.log( fn.call(function() { return upper.call(str)}) ); // AAA
```

In your example, `fn()` is attempting to call `call` but it's not specifying the context, which typically defaults to the `window` object but in this case it just makes it `undefined`, which triggers a weird error in Chrome (as you discovered), but Firefox is clearer about the problem,

> TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined

Comment: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1):

> So, when is a function, not a function?

The function is a function, but you are not executing it correctly, as explained in comments and the answer by @deceze

> I noticed a weird thing in javascript.

You seem confused by the message that you are getting in the environment in which you tested, the message is not strictly correct.

> Uncaught TypeError: `fn` is not a function

The current stable version of chromium (40.0.2214.91 on my linux install, chrome fails to run on my hardware without making settings changes), chrome being the environment on which you tested, gives a seemingly more correct error message that makes more sense.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So, were you asking/wanting to ask a serious question or were you just poking a little fun at a mistake in a version of chrome?

Comment: `40.0.2214.91` is not the current stable version of Chrome; [`43.0.2357.81` is](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/06/stable-update-for-chrome-os.html). The package source you're getting Chrome from is not up to date. Also, I'd just like to make the distinguishing point that (even if the OP knew the answer to this question before asking), wanting to create a repository of information about this very confusing error is far cry from "poking fun".

Comment: I've lots of other work to do rather than poking a little fun at chrome. And FYI, I came across this stuff while answering [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594471/array-prototype-map-is-not-a-function-when-passing-a-function-generated-by-funct/30594762#30594762) and not everyone uses the chrome version you use(and I don't update chrome manually, it happens automatically) and thanks for your answer. Thanks for the comment above mine too.

Comment: On Fedora 19 it is 40.0.2214.91, which updates automatically using YUM from a package repository, I don't intend to build it myself (and I just remembered this is chromium rather than chrome). I understand that different OS's have different stable versions, and there are bound to be differences. Ok, you did not include that information in your question, so you were really trying to check that you have answered another question correctly? Or I still don't really understand what this question is or what kind of answer you are expecting?